# Reasoning about a sequence of consecutive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers

Let:

- $p_n$ be the $n$th prime so that $p_1=2, p_2=3,$ etc.
- $\text{lpf}(x)$ be the [least prime factor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastPrimeFactor.html) of $x$.
- $P$ be a set of $n$ distinct prime numbers that is not the same as the first $n$ primes (it includes at least one prime $q > p_n$)
- $F$ be the set of the first $n$ primes.
- $S(T)$ be the size of the longest sequence of consecutive integers such that the least prime factor of each integer in the set $T$.

For example if $F = \text{\{}2\text{\}}$, then $S(F)=1$.  If $F$=$\text{\{}2,3\text{\}}$, then $S(F)=3$.

Does it follow that $S(F) \ge S(P)$?

This seems obvious to me but my intuitions are often not correct.

I was thinking that if it as obviously true as it seems, it should be straight forward to prove.

I tried to prove it but found myself unable to complete the proof which makes me wonder if my intuition is wrong or if this is an open question that does not have a proof.

---

Here's the start of the argument that I attempted but could not finish:

(1)  Let $s > 1, x+1, \dots, x+s$ be any sequence of consecutive integers where $\forall i, x+1 \le i \le x+s, \text{lpf}(i) \in P$

(2)  Let $O(pos_1=\text{lpf}(x+1), pos_2=\text{lpf}(x+2), \dots, pos_s=\text{lpf}(x+s))$ be an ordered list of the first occurrence of each distinct least prime factor.

So, for $x=19, s=9$, the ordered list of least prime factors would be $O(pos_1=2, pos_2=3, pos_3=23, pos_4=5, pos_5=29)$

(3) I would posit that it is possible to find a sequence of the same or greater length with least prime factors less than or equal to $p_n$.  We can do this by creating an ordered list where all primes less than $p_n$ are preserved and all the other primes are replaced by a smaller prime.

So a sequence of consecutive integers can be found using the Chinese Remainder Theorem and $O(pos_1=2, pos_2=3, pos_3=7, pos_4=5, pos_5=11)$.

In this case $x=199$ so that the range is: $200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209$.

(4)  This approach clearly works if any prime included greater than $p_n$ does not divide more than one integer in the sequence.

(5)  It seems to me that it is not possible for any prime $q > p_n$ to divide more than one integer in the sequence.  Assume that it does so that there exists two integers in the sequence $x_2 > x1$ that have $q$ as least prime factor.

(6) Since $x_2 - x_1 = 2q$, it follows that $s > 2q > 2p_n$ and that the least prime factors of $x_1, x_1+1, \dots, x_2-1, x_2$ are in $P$.

(7) I am not clear how to show that $x_1, x_1+1, \dots, x_1+2p_n$ consists of more than $n$ distinct least prime factors.  If this can be shown, then there is a contradiction and the assumption in (5) can be rejected.

Comment: Is $S(F_n)=p_{n+1}-2$?  Just taking the set $\{2, 3, \cdots, p_{n+1}-1\}$ as maximal...

Comment: For trivially small sets, $S(F_n)$ is clear.  For larger sets, I know of no way of proving the size.  I know that $p_{n+1}-2$ is not the maximum size.  I suspect that the maximum size is $2(p_{n-1}-1)+1$.  For examples of a larger sequence and why I believe this, check out my question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/445861/15915).

Comment: Short thought: isn't $F(S)$ equal to one less than the Jacobsthal function evaluated at the primorials? For instance, for $n=5$, we have $S(F)=13$, with the smallest example at $[114,126]$. The Jacobsthal function is the length of the shortest sequence of numbers coprime to it's argument; evaluated at primorials, it's essentially the largest gap provided by the wheel sieve $W_{p_n}$. Here, $J(2310)=J(11\#)=h(5)=14$ because, e.g., $127-113=14$.

Comment: @EricSnyder, yes,  $S(F_n)$ is related to the [Jacobsthal function](https://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function).  Where the Jacobsthal function is known, with $p_k \le n < p_{k+1}$, then $S(F_{k}) = $ Jacobsthal function$(n)-1$ I believe.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't $S(P)$ be one less than the Jacobsthal function on the product of the set of primes in $P$? Not absolutely sure here--the "least prime factor" condition is different from coprimality. For, say, $P=\{2,3,5,7,13\}$, we can safely say $S(P) < 13$, but for $P=\{2,3,5,7,97\}$, we can still be sure $S(P)<22$, as that's the longest distance between even multiples of $11$. I don't know that this helps you, but some food for thought.

Comment: Actually, for P= {2,3,5,7,13}, $S(P) \ge 13$.  Consider $7884, \dots, 7896$.  Your comment helps!  Any maximum should be consistent with the Jacobsthal function!  :-)

Comment: This paper (obtained via OEIS) indicates that the answer to your question is NO, with the first counterexamples at $n=24$: https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-2012-02581-6

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks, @EricSnyder  I had a feeling that my intuition was wrong.  So, that explains why I couldn't complete the argument!   :-)

Comment: Oops... I should note that I didn't actually show that the Jacobsthal function on the product was equivalent to your function. And yes, it looks like I was mistaken about the size of $S(P)$ for that one, though it still isn't *larger* than $S(F)$. Note that the first example occurs much earlier at $[294, 306]$.